# Integrated buck regulator capable of 12A

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck

I was narrowing down design options on digikey for a buck regulator capable of 5v and 8A continuous currents when i came across the following part which integrates the FETs and is capable of wide supply range and 12A continuous output current at a price point $1.46

http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ2255LQI-31.pdf

There aren't too many graphs in the datasheet to form an informed opinion and the ones they have are using a 1V output rail.

If this does as it says on the tin it would save me the trouble of picking various sub components. Is there anything that stands out in this part that makes it a no go for your designs?

I want to power an LED strip which when fully white runs at 6.9A. Design spec is input voltage 24V and output voltage 5V. The datasheet included looks like it should comfortably support this. Am i missing something?

Comment: Added more information. The load is an LED strip. This part looks like it would work. But then it says it uses an LDO to bring down the voltage to 5.3V. That alone makes me think it will get too hot (my input is a 24V rail).

Comment: Hasman, you should probably [take the two minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to remind you why folk give their free time to help.

Comment: The 5.3V is used to power the device's internal circuits, not the load.

Comment: I am aware of that but the 5.3V is generated using an LDO. So they're gonna bring my 24V supply voltage down to 5.3V using a linear regulator? That sounds like a horrible idea?

Comment: What's the alternative? Another buck converter to power this one? The current required will probably be only a few tens of mA, if that.